# Data storage in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

first of all please forgive me for asking a silly question but I am new to mongodb and just installed it on my windows platform by following this installation guide :http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

It says "MongoDB requires a data folder to store its files. The default location for the MongoDB data directory is C:\data\db.You can specify an alternate path for data files using the --dbpath option to mongod.exe."

So I created a folder d://data/db in my computer and issued a command
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\mongodb\data

Then it says
"At the mongo.exe prompt, issue the following two commands to insert a record in the test collection of the default test database and then retrieve that record:

```
db.test.save( { a: 1 } )
db.test.find()"
```

I issued this to commands to save and retrieve the objects and its working fine but what is this default test database? where is it? Moreover  where this object is stored? Where I can find this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is this default test database?

When you connect to a mongod server without specifying a database, a default database "test" is selected. Since databases are created lazily, it may not even exist until you write to it.

```
db.test.save( { a: 1 } )
```

After this line is executed, database with current name ("test" by default) is created (if didn't exist already) and in it, collection "test" is created (if didn't exist already).

> where is it? Moreover where this object is stored? Where I can find this file?

All databases are ultimately stored as files in your data dir. Look for "test.*" files there.

Comment: Thankyou, can you please tell me about the files test.0,test.1,test.ns and the two folders journal,_tmp created.

Comment: That's your test database and its journal.

Comment: @saumyaraj, read this about DB storage files http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database

Comment: @DenisNikanorov Thankyou,can you tell me about mongod.lock file and database.ns file.

Comment: @saumyaraj, ns file hold info about database namespace. .lock file I think hold info about read/write database lock I am but not sure. This is database service fileы. What do you want to know about them?

Comment: @DenisNikanorov Just wanted to know the purpose of the files.

Comment: @DenisNikanorov: mongod.lock file holds the PID of current daemon. If the file exists and is not empty, then the daemon is probably running right now. Or crashed abruptly some time ago.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, thanks! I just checked it and there is really process id of mongod.

Answer (score 0):

mongod.lock, is the file which provides the PID of your running mongod instance. When you start a mongod instance, MongoDB check if the lock is empty to start cleanly mongod. Then MongoDB registered the PID number of the running mongod instance in this lock file.

MongoDB delete the contains of this lock file when you shutdown cleanly your server,

```
mongod --shutdown -- dbpath <path name> --port <port number>
```